# Highlighting column headings if any of the cells in that column contains red colour

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the macro world, I am trying to write the VBA to highlight the column heading in Red (7th Row is column heading in my sheet)  if any of the cells in that column contains red colour if not then the column heading should be highlighted as green. I tried the below code but it is highlighting all the column heading as green.

```
Dim headers As Range, body As Range

Set headers = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(7).Columns
Set body = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Columns

For Each body In Range(Range("A11:BD11"), Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If body.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        headers.Interior.Color = IIf(found, vbRed, vbGreen)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is `found`?  it's neither declared nor set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim body As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change Sheet1 for the name of the sheet

With ws
    For Each body In .Range(.Range("A11"), .Range("BD" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If body.Interior.Color = vbRed And _
            Not .Cells(1, body.Column).Interior.Color = IIf(found, vbRed, vbGreen) Then 'To avoid doing it each time a cell on the same colour meets the criteria
            .Cells(1, body.Column).Interior.Color = IIf(found, vbRed, vbGreen)
       End If
    Next
End With
```

You were taking ranges wrong, and when looping a range you don't set the variable before. It will be set on the For loop

Comment: Something is wrong with your Range in the `For Each` -statement.

Comment: Thanks Damian, which row is considered as here. I was using row 7 as heading

Comment: Thanks Damian, which row is considered as heading here. I was using row 7 as heading

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to declare where to take the rows on the range. If it helped you please mark it as answer so others might find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Set the range to loop
        Set rng = .Range("A11:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        'Loop range
        For Each cell In rng

            If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                'If cell interior is red then color Header(Row 7)
                .Cells(7, cell.Column).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                'Exit the loop after the first match
                Exit For
            Else
                'If there is no match leave no fill
                .Cells(7, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```